# Printing particularities of pgf77 (FORTRAN 77 behaviour?)

Tags: formatting, fortran

I compile and run this simple FORTRAN 77 program:

```
      program test
      write(6,*) '- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ',
     &           '- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -'
      write(6,'(2G15.5)') 0.1,0.0
      end
```

with `gfortran` or `f95` the output is:

```
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    0.10000         0.0000
```

with `pgf77` it is:

```
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    0.10000        0.00000E+00
```

and with `g77` or `ifort`:

```
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    0.10000         0.0000
```

A couple of questions arise:

1. Why is 0.0 printed with four decimal places instead of five, as
   requested in the format `G15.5`? Is this spec-compliant? And why
   does `pgf77` write it differently?
2. I guess the line break in the `- - - - - -` line with the last three
   compilers is due to some limitation in the output line length... Is
   there any way of increasing this limit, or otherwise force
   single-line writes, at compile time?

By the way, the desired output is

```
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    0.10000         0.00000
```

which matches none of the above.

Comment: as pgf77 is a commercial product you should fairly ask support about the g formatting (and let us know the response..).

Comment: @george I did ask them, and got basically the same answer: there's nothing that can be done. http://www.pgroup.com/userforum/viewtopic.php?t=4000

Comment: looking at the standard http://www.fortran.com/F77_std/rjcnf0001-sh-13.html#sh-13.2.1 I'm inclined to agree pgf77 has the proper f77 form for the zero. The others obviously follow the newer standard.

Answer (score 3):

Exactly what the `G` edit descriptor causes to be printed is a little complicated but for the value `0.0` the standard (10.7.5.2.2 in the 2008 edition) states that the compiler should print a representation with `d-1` (ie 4 in your example) digits in the fractional part of the number.  So most of your compilers are behaving correctly; I think that `pgf77` is incorrect but it may be working to an earlier standard with a different requirement.

The simplest fix for this is probably to use an `f` edit descriptor instead, `(2F15.5)`.

As for the printing of the lines of hyphens, your use of the `*` edit descriptor, which causes *list-directed* output, surrenders precise control of the output to the compiler.  My opinion is that it is a little perverse of a compiler to print the two parts of the expression on two lines but it is not non-standard behaviour.

If you want the hyphens printed all on one line take control of the output format, `write(6,'(2A24)')` or something similar ought to do it (I didn't count the hyphens for you, just guessed that there are 24 in each part of the output.)  If that doesn't appeal to you simply write one string with all the hyphens in; that will probably get written on one line even using list-directed output.

Comment: Well, in my real case I have to work with a large program written by lots of different people over more than 20 years, so that's why I asked for some compiler flag rather than modifying the printing formats.

Comment: I fear that you will search in vain for a compiler flag which, in effect, says *format output as I would like it to be formatted rather than as the code says it can be formatted*.  If you don't want the (standard) `G` edit descriptor behaviour, use another edit descriptor. *Etc*

Comment: fyi that example can be fixed simply by changing the comma to // .. which just as a matter of style is how it should be anyway assuming that is supposed to be one string.